# how to add items to combo box in lightswitch

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I'm new to lightswitch and i searched lot, but couldn't find proper solution for this simple question. I need to add items to combo box, based on user selection. ( not from existing table)

For example if user select country ,following towns must add to combo box.

```
USA - Texas, New York etc
UK  - London , Surrey
```

How can i do this? i'm using vb.net as my back end. i found this article [How to create an unbound combobox](http://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/how-to-create-an-unbound-combobox-in-microsoft-ligthswitch/)  as useful one. but couldn't able work according to my scenario.

what is the way to add items to combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't directly assign our own values to combo box. we have to use either data table ( as mentioned by embedded.kyle ) or we have to create custom control to assign values.

i have used custom User Control for above scenario.  detail step that i followed can be found in following [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/user-control-in-lightswitch-2011/)

Answer (score 3):

In Lightswitch, if you want to have a dynamic set of data bound to a control, that data *must* be in a table. You then need to create a query that filters the data in that table based on the user's selection and bind your control to that query.

Here is a pair of articles that describes implementing a situation that is similar to yours:

[Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry](https://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

[Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry Part 2](https://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a record that doesn't already exist in a bound table is a very common scenario. Unfortunately, there's no out-of-the-box way to do this in LightSwitch, you simply have to write code to achieve it, like in this blog post.

[Add non existent records using AutoCompleteBox](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/lightswitch-add-non-existent-records-using-autocompletebox/)

Or, of course as was also suggested, you could create a custom control to do the job.